# How to safely pop FragmentManager's back stack after the state is already saved

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment-backstack

So, if I want to e.g. replace Fragment, I can do the following:

```
    ft.replace(R.id.frame, newFragment);
    if (mFragmentManager.isStateSaved()) {
        ft.commitAllowingStateLoss();
    } else {
        ft.commit();
    }
```

The above code will not throw the notorious `IllegalStateException` if it's run after the state is saved.

However, when it comes to popping the backstack, I can't find an analogously safe way of doing things.

So, is there any safe way to pop `FragmentManager`'s backstack after the state had already been saved?

Comment: Check out this [article about Fragment Transactions & Activity State Loss](https://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/08/fragment-transaction-commit-state-loss.html), Described the issue in details and **How to avoid the exception**.

Comment: @KhaledLela, I'm familiar with this article. It doesn't address the question of popping the backstack.

Comment: Please have a look to comments related with the article.

Comment: @KhaledLela, I did. Still can't see anything that would look as an answer to my question.